# Import OpenStreetMaps data fails

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, nominatim

I work in project of geocoding and I want to import the OpenStreetMaps data. I created a database and named it `nominatim` and I tried this command:

```
sudo ./utils/setup.php --osm-file morocco-latest.osm.pbf --all –osm2pgsql-cache 18000 2>&1 | tee setup.log
```

it shows me this message :

```
CREATE DB 
ERROR: database already exists ( pgsql : // @/nominatim)
```

After I delete my database `nominatim` it shows this error message:

```
ERROR: unable to find /usr/pgsql-9.3/share/contrib/postgis-1.5/postgis.sq
```

BTW: I installed postgres with all the package.

Comment: crosspost: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143697/import-openstreetmaps-data-fails

Comment: The [installation instructions](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation#Import_and_index_OSM_data) don't say anything about creating the Nominatim database yourself. And *postgis.sql* belongs to the postgis package, try reinstalling it.

Answer (score 1):

I have just stumbled on this error and here is how I resolved it.
Edit the file

> ./utils/setup.php

and comment the following lines.

```
//array('create-db', '', 0, 1, 0, 0, 'bool', 'Create nominatim db'),
```

and the whole function where the database is created.

```
/**if ($aCMDResult['create-db'] || $aCMDResult['all']) {
echo "Create DB\n";
$bDidSomething = true;
$oDB = DB::connect(CONST_Database_DSN, false);
if (!PEAR::isError($oDB)) {
    fail('database already exists ('.CONST_Database_DSN.')');
}
passthruCheckReturn('createdb -E UTF-8 -p '.$aDSNInfo['port'].' '.$aDSNInfo['database']);
```

}**/

If you now run the command, it will skip the db creation and carry out the importing. Once all done remove the comments from the file.

Answer (score 1):

You also can drop nomination database by

```
sudo -su postgres
dropdb nominatim
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the database name in the following location

```
Nominatim/settings/
```

Edit the database name in this file `settings.php`.

```
@define('CONST_Database_DSN', 'pgsql://@/nominatim');
```

change with your database name

```
 @define('CONST_Database_DSN', 'pgsql://@/nominatimMorocco');
```

If you change your database name here than you also need to change following nominatim installation command.

```
./utils/specialphrases.php --countries > specialphrases_countries.sql
 psql -d nominatimMorocco -f specialphrases_countries.sql

./utils/specialphrases.php --wiki-import > specialphrases.sql
 psql -d nominatimMorocco -f specialphrases.sql
```